Windows Firewall creating custom rule for port forwarding - confusing fields
I've got quite some experience with TCP port forwarding in the UNIX world (netcat, iptables) but now I need to do the same on Windows Server 2022.
Client machines can reach TCP 25 on "gateway" server (we control this firewall). This "gateway" server can reach SMTP relay out there somewhere (we don't control that path).
We don't want to maintain SMTP relay on the "gateway" server, instead, just forward TCP 25 through it. More ports to come later. UDP too.
Temporary solution would be with netsh, but even that doesn't work:
On the "gateway":
telnet a.b.c.d 25 - this works, I get SMTP hello and can create email from telnet prompt.
Started wf.msc and made a new standard inbound rule for tcp 25, accept all remote addresses. This is topmost allow rule, so I presume nothing is bocking inbound TCP 25 on the gateway server.
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=25 connectport=25 connectaddress=a.b.c.d
netsh interface portproxy show all -  looks good, proxy is enabled for all interfaces
telnet 127.0.0.1 25 - connection failed.
What is "failed", anyway? What does it mean? Is it TCP NAK. i.e. "refused". or something else?
This was just an intermediate test, anyway.
Preferred long-term solution would be to do TCP port forwarding with a permanent rule in Defender on the gateway host. Here/s what I tried:
Removed that "standard" inbound allow rule for TCP 25 mentioned before, and tried to create the "custom" input rule.
Confusing is what is meant by "remote addresse(s)" and even ranges field there.
How can one forward to many addresses or even ranges?
I suspect it still means source IPs for incoming connections.
But then, where else can I specify the destination IP to forward to?
Or am I looking at the wrong solution?
Please don't suggest 3rd party apps, we are strictly bundled to MS tools & features.

Is the Internet connection really a business connection, not a residential connection? Residential connections will typically block port 25.

Your issue needs to be investigated across multiple layers of the network and system configuration.
Have you verified that the netsh interface portproxy rule for port 25 is correctly configured, and that the firewall is allowing inbound traffic on port 25 from all remote IP addresses without any conflicting or restrictive rules?
After setting the portproxy rule, did you check the current configuration with:

netsh interface portproxy show all

Is the gateway server actively listening on TCP port 25?
You can verify this by running:

netstat -an | findstr :25

Can you successfully connect to the external SMTP server (a.b.c.d) on port 25 from the gateway using telnet?
Example:

telnet a.b.c.d 25

When you run telnet 127.0.0.1 25 on the gateway, do you get a "connection refused" or "connection failed" error?
Is there any third-party antivirus or firewall software on the gateway that could be blocking the port forwarding?
Does the gateway require specific routing configuration to reach the external SMTP server, such as static routes?
Have you checked the Windows Event Logs for any errors related to port forwarding or netsh?
Are there any outbound firewall rules that might be blocking traffic from the gateway to the external SMTP server?
Have you ensured that the forwarding rule is applied to the correct network interface(s) on the gateway?

On the gateway, I have added a new Inbound rule on top of all, to allow TCP 25, so I presume the local firewall should pass it on all interfaces including loopback. telnet 127.0.0.1 25 says "connection failed", not "refused", which is puzzling me - on Linux, I never saw "failed" connections, it's either ACK or NACK. Yes, I can reach the external SMTP server with telnet and yes, netstat shows port 25 listening. Yes I checked the forwarding with "netsh interface portproxy show all" and it shows listening on "*" interfaces
